# Как убрать "Select", пример на скриншоте

Tags: javascript, html, css, joomla

Добрый день, подскажете пожалуйста как убрать надпись Select по умолчанию с выпадающего списка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот скрин кода с инспектора:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот код генерируется автоматически используя модуль K2 Joomla, поэтому в ручную я не могу его отредактировать.
Кто что может посоветовать?
Спасибо.

Comment: это псевдоселект, а значит html неинформативен и нужно видеть каким javascript-кодом он генерируется и как этот код вызывается.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Пример 1**

```html
<select>
    <option value="-1" style="display:none;">Select</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

**Пример 2**

http://jsfiddle.net/pyh64yvz/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
    
    $('#select').prop("selectedIndex", -1);    
    
    var offset = $('#select').offset();
    offset.top += 3;
    offset.left += 3;
    $('#select_new').offset(offset);    
    
    $('#select').change(function() {
        if ($(this).prop("selectedIndex") != -1) {
            $('#select_new').hide();
        }
    });
    
});
```

```css
.wrap-select{
    position: relative;
    font-family: Arial;            
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 20px;
}
#select_new {    
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    color: #000;
    position: absolute;
}
select {
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap-select">
<span id="select_new">Default message</span>
    
    <select id="select">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>  
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Идея хороша, но как я писал я не имею доступ к коду он генерируется автоматически.

Comment: А теперь открой это в IE и убедись, что оно там не работает.

Comment: Да посмотрел - да работает не корректно  сделал второй вариант

Answer (score 0):

Есть один способ который помогает вам! Проверите подключенный `js` коды! Откройте каждый `js` коды и нажмите `Ctrl+F` и появляется поисковый блок. И туда написать Select [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и просто удаляйте!

Answer (score 0):

Самому пришлось заниматься этим, поэтому вот вариант с css стилем

```
#xf_1 option[value="0"]{
display: none;}
```